# Unable to execute "dotnet ef migrations add init" when OnConfiguring() defined in partial class

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

Here are the steps to reproduce the problem I met:

1. Clone my code

   ```bash
   git clone https://github.com/doggy8088/EFCore7UnableDoMigration.git
   cd EFCore7UnableDoMigration
   ```
2. Do the migration

   ```bash
   dotnet ef migrations add init
   ```

   Errors below:

   > Unable to create an object of type 'ContosoUniversityContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

Here is what I do:

1. I added a `Data\ContosoUniversityContextPartial.cs` partial class which are defined a constructor with no parameters and a `OnConfiguring` method.

   I reference from this doc: [Design-time DbContext Creation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-4015686&tabs=dotnet-core-cli#using-a-constructor-with-no-parameters)
2. I expected my DbContext class should able to recognized by `dotnet-ef` tool.

#### version information

- EF Core version: `7.0.10`
- Database provider: `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`
- Target framework: `.NET 7.0`
- Operating system: `Windows 10`
- IDE: `N/A`

Comment: I think it's a bug in EF Core command line tool. Some notes here: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/31527

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To instantiate the context, EF Core use `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`. But it has a weird behavior and don't choose the desired the constructor. All detail in this issue :

[ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance depends on the order of constructors' definitions](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/46132)

It's already fixed in .NET 8 preview.

To resolve the problem, you can wait .NET 8 (release at November) or update `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` to the preview (compatible with older .NET version).